# Extracting substring from a string

Tags: powershell

Struggling to extract value within square brackets from below strings using PowerShell

```
in relation to any Facility C Loan [?10%?] per cent. per annum;
"Facility A Commitments" means the aggregate of the Facility A Commitments, being [????????10 million?????] at the date of this Agreement.
```

Output required:

```
10%
10 million
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a single, multiline string in memory (PSv4+):

```
$str = @'
in relation to any Facility C Loan [?10%?] per cent. per annum;
"Facility A Commitments" means the aggregate of the Facility A Commitments, being [????????10 million?????] at the date of this Agreement.
'@

[regex]::matches($str,'\[\?+([^?]+)\?+\]').ForEach({ $_.Groups[1].Value })
```

Using the pipeline with `Get-Content` and `Select-String` for line-by-line processing (PSv3+):

```
$lines = @'
in relation to any Facility C Loan [?10%?] per cent. per annum;
"Facility A Commitments" means the aggregate of the Facility A Commitments, being [????????10 million?????] at the date of this Agreement.
'@ -split '\r?\n'

# Substitute your `Get-Content someFile.txt` call for $lines
$lines |
  Select-String '\[\?+([^?]+)\?+\]' |
    ForEach-Object { $_.Matches.Groups[1].Value }
```

Explanation of regex `\[\?+([^?]+)\?+\]`:

- `\[` matches a literal `[`
- `\?+` matches one or more (`+`) literal `?`
- `([^?]+)` is a capture group (`(...)`) that matches one or more (`+`) characters from the set of characters (`[...]`) that are *not* (`^`) part of the set, i.e., any character that is *not* the `?` character - this is the value of interest to extract.
- `\?+` matches one or more literal `?`
- `\]` matches a literal `]`

`[regex]::Matches()` and the `.Matches` property on the objects that `Select-String` emits is a collection of `[System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match]` objects, whose `.Groups` property contains both the full match (index `0`) and what each capture group captured (`1` containing the 1st capture group's value, ...).

Answer (score 0):

This is your regex for both cases:

```
(?<=\[\?+)[^\?]*(?=\?+\])
```

You can play with it at https://regex101.com
But this does not support non-fixed width look behinds (the first plus). It should work in .NET/PowerShell though.

This will be good for you:

https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Answer (score -1):

For the first one run:

```
$message -match '\[\?(\d*%)\?\]'
echo $Matches[1]
```

For the second one:

```
\[\?*(\d* million)\?*\]
echo $Matches[1]
```

In each iteration you can simple as if `$message -match '...'` returns $True, than check the values inside $Matches variable (this is a system variable to hold the result of the regex.

Comment: how to use this with select-object... im getting results from select-string

get-content "My.doc" | select-string -pattern "in relation to any faclity" | Select-object Path,LineNumber, Line

Comment: in LINE... i get the content - in relation to any Facility C Loan [?10%?] per cent. per annum

how to apply your above expression to this LINE object (which contains the data)

Comment: This is poor solution, you use knowledge about the variables being sought and you make up for the imperfect regex by post-processing the result.